# Как получить одну из TXT записей домена в Python

Tags: python, dns, txt, domain

У меня есть программа на Python. Мне хочется сделать в ней получение информации об актуальной версии через мой домен. Я создал TXT запись в своём домене. Как получить эту txt запись при помощи кода и поместить в переменную?

Comment: что такое "txt запись" и что вы имеете в виду под "в своем домене"?

Comment: Сомнительная затея, потому что промежуточные DNS-серверы будут кэшировать запись на много дней

Answer (score 0):

Если я корректно понял, при запросе(ex. `https://example.com/version.txt`) сайт возвращает содержимое файла, в данном случае версию. Я бы посоветовал возвращать версию иначе(например, из кода). В противном случае, если всё-таки используете txt файл, убедитесь в том, что он нигде не кешируется(иначе он будет меняться с задержкой)
Вот пример кода, получающий содержимое по адресу `https://pastebin.com/raw/Lc3Y15BZ`:

```
import requests

version_url = "https://pastebin.com/raw/Lc3Y15BZ"

response = requests.get(version_url)
if response.ok:
    print(f"Actual version: {response.text}")
else:
    print("Failed to check")
```

Comment: Это не DNS, а HTTP, и это не TXT-запись, а TXT-файл, так что мимо